# W/System: A resource failed to call release. Broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, webrtc

When I try to get broadcast for incomming call:

```
    BroadcastReceiver br = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    MainApplication.getAppContext().registerReceiver(br, filter);
```

I got an error when doing or receiving a call:

```
W/System: A resource failed to call release.
```

The `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` works fine, but `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` do not. My APP has a webRTC connection open. In other APP that dosen't work with webRTC, `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` works fine.

I'm trying to make the audio back to speaker after a incomming call.

Some clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I haven't set uses-permission in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

And of course, you have to ask the user to use the PHONE_STATE.

React-native way:

```
     (async () => {
        try {
          const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            {
              'title': 'ReactNativeCode Location Permission',
              'message': 'ReactNativeCode App needs access to your phone state '
            }
          )
          if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            Alert.alert("Location Permission Granted.");
          }
          else {
            Alert.alert("Location Permission Not Granted");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.warn(err)
        }
    })()
```